# Evaluation of RadioButtonList control using JavaScript - ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am developing a website using asp.net and C#.

I am using a RadioButtonList control. The code snippet for RadioButtonList is shown below

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RLCompareParameter" runat="server" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" meta:resourcekey="rsKey_RLCompareParameter" 
            AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="RLCompareParameter_SelectedIndexChanged">
          <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Forms" meta:resourcekey="rsKey_RLCompareParameterListItemForms" Text="Forms"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="Segments" meta:resourcekey="rsKey_RLCompareParameterListItemSegments" Text="Segments"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="Questions" meta:resourcekey="rsKey_RLCompareParameterListItemQuestions" Text="Questions"></asp:ListItem>
     </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

There is a button in the same page. While clicking on that button i want to display an alert message based on the selected radio list item using javascript. Some part of my javascript function is shown below

```
  var RLCompareParameter = this.document.getElementById("<%= RLCompareParameter.ClientID %>");
         if (RLCompareParameter.SelectedValue == "Forms") {
             if (document.getElementById("<%= lbAvailableForms.ClientID %>").value == "") {
                 alert("Please select a form from Available Evaluation Forms ");
                 return false;
             }


         } else if (RLCompareParameter.SelectedValue == "Segments") {
             if (document.getElementById("<%= lbAvailableSegments.ClientID %>").value == "") {
                 alert("Please select a segment from the available segments ");
                 return false;
             }
         } else if (RLCompareParameter.SelectedValue == "Questions") {
             if (document.getElementById("<%= lbAvailableQuestions.ClientID %>").value == "") {
                 alert("Please select a Question from the available questions");
                 return false;

             } 
         }
```

But the if(RLCompareParameter.SelectedValue == "some value") always false. i think there is no attribute like selected value for RadioButtonList control. I hope someone help me

Comment: oh sorry. i am mistyped. there is no error. See the edited Question .it just bypassing the if statement. And  i dont know how to evaluate a RadioButtonList using javascript. is the abpve java snippet is correct? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In html, there is no such thing as a RadioButtonList. Your `RLCompareParameter` variable will be a reference to the table or span that is containing the three input elements (thats what the ASP.NET control outputs into your page). `SelectedValue` is only for ASP.NET code, not javascript.

You will have to get a reference to the specific `input` element itself and look at its `checked` property in your if statements to see whether that radio button is selected or not. There are several ways to do this. Here's one that might work:

```
 var RLCompareParameter = document.getElementById("<%= RLCompareParameter.ClientID %>");
 var radioButtons = RLCompareParameter.getElementsByTagName('input');

 if (radioButtons[0].checked) {
     if (document.getElementById("<%= lbAvailableForms.ClientID %>").value == "") {
         alert("Please select a form from Available Evaluation Forms ");
         return false;
     }
 } else if (radioButtons[1].checked) {
     if (document.getElementById("<%= lbAvailableSegments.ClientID %>").value == "") {
         alert("Please select a segment from the available segments ");
         return false;
     }
 } else if (radioButtons[2].checked) {
     if (document.getElementById("<%= lbAvailableQuestions.ClientID %>").value == "") {
         alert("Please select a Question from the available questions");
         return false;

     } 
 }
```